# My JRadioButton won't work with my action listener

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, listener, jradiobutton

So I'm making a program that finds out the surface area and the volume of polyhedrons, so I need to use `JRadioButton`s to let the user select what shape they want, if they want SurfaceArea or Volume, and stuff like that.

However, I ran into a problem that requires me to make something run every time that a new button is clicked.

When I added an `actionListener()` to my `JRadioButton`, the `actionPerformed()` method didn't even run. Is there something that I am missing?

I want my actionPerformed()method to run.

```
width.addActionListener(ral);
height.addActionListener(ral);
length.addActionListener(ral);
slantHeight.addActionListener(ral);
radius.addActionListener(ral);
displayAnswer.addActionListener(ral);


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    System.out.println("Changed Radio Button: " + a.getSource());
}
```

Comment: Per the site's FAQ: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Please create and post your [mcve] so we can test your code ourselves.

Comment: +Hovercraft Full Of Eels    Is this better?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out what is wrong based on what you've posted. Hopefully some one smarter than me will answer this, but if this doesn't happen, please consider creating and posting your [mcve]. It's a useful tool even for debugging things yourself, and so you've nothing to lose in the attempt.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you explain what you want in detail please? +Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @LtLobster You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem" if you're still confused.

Comment: Lobster, have a look at the link, it will explain all! And even if you don't need the construct for this question, it will be useful to you in the future, I can assure you.

Comment: Myself, I rarely add listeners to my JRadioButtons, but rather simply query their state when the user presses the accept or submit JButton, or performs a similar action. This way my code can be much simpler -- something that I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to Write an Item Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) (emphasis mine):

> Item events are fired by components that implement the [`ItemSelectable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/ItemSelectable.html) interface. Generally, `ItemSelectable` components **maintain on/off state for one or more items**.

Since a radio button fits this description, [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) would be a more suitable listener to use; try that instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @LtLobster If you found this answer useful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, this is what I mean by a small-"ish" compilable runnable program that demonstrates a problem. Here I demonstrate **not** adding action listeners or any listeners to JRadioButtons but rather adding a single listener to a JButton (actually an AbstractAction which is like an ActionListener on steroids). This uses ButtonGroup objects to allow only one JRadioButton to be selected per group, and to allow the code to query which button was selected. The ButtonGroup will return the "model" for the selected JRadioButton, and then we extract the actionCommand String from this model:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyMcve extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] SHAPES = {
        "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"
    };
    private static final String[] COLORS = {
        "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue" 
    };
    private ButtonGroup shapeButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();    
    private ButtonGroup colorButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    public MyMcve() {
        JPanel shapesBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        shapesBtnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Shapes"));
        for (String shape : SHAPES) {
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(shape);
            radioButton.setActionCommand(shape);
            shapeButtonGroup.add(radioButton);
            shapesBtnPanel.add(radioButton);
        }
        JPanel colorsBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        colorsBtnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Colors"));
        for (String color : COLORS) {
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(color);
            radioButton.setActionCommand(color);
            colorButtonGroup.add(radioButton);
            colorsBtnPanel.add(radioButton);
        }

        JPanel bothButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        bothButtonPanel.add(shapesBtnPanel);
        bothButtonPanel.add(colorsBtnPanel);


        JButton getSelectionBtn = new JButton(new GetSelectionAction("Get Selection"));
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(getSelectionBtn);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(bothButtonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class GetSelectionAction extends AbstractAction {
        public GetSelectionAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String shapeSelection = "";
            String colorSelection = "";
            ButtonModel shapeModel = shapeButtonGroup.getSelection();
            if (shapeModel != null) {
                shapeSelection = shapeModel.getActionCommand();
            }

            ButtonModel colorModel = colorButtonGroup.getSelection();
            if (colorModel != null) {
                colorSelection = colorModel.getActionCommand();
            }

            System.out.println("Selected Shape: " + shapeSelection);
            System.out.println("Selected Color: " + colorSelection);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyMcve mainPanel = new MyMcve();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```